# How do you choose alternate glyphs for a character?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts

I'm working with the [Gotham font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotham_(typeface)#Variations), and it has alternate glyphs for the same unicode character. For example, at 0031, it has one character under GID 388, but another character under GID 257.

Is there any way I can specify the GID used?

Examples, as seen in Photoshop:

GID 257
[image]

GID 388
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, programmatically that's not possible with AS3/Flash, the only way I see is to create another remapped font based on `Gotham`.